# How can I get the first blank row in a database?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm writing in Java a simple program that write a database with informations inserted by user.
I've implemented a Listener to a button that saves these informations, updating therefore a connected Server (so the connection is ok).
I'd like to get the first blank row and write on it. In this way, I can write the entire database calling ever the same method.
Any suggestion?
this is the code (it begins from a listener)

```
Object src = e.getSource();
            if (src == insTeaching)
            {
                String teachName = teachNameField.getText();
                int studentsNumber = (int) studentsNumberSpinner.getValue();
                DBConnect connection = new DBConnect();
connection.updateDB(teachName, studentSNumber);
}
```

where updateDB is the following method:

```
public void updateDB (String name, int student){ 
try {
    String query1 = "UPDATE subject SET name='" + name
+"', student='" + student+"' WHERE (conditions...);
    PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement(query1);
    statement.executeUpdate();
```

Obviously this method can't work at this time.. how can I implemnts it for having the writing on the first blank row? In this way I can evoke the method every time the user click on the button..
Is my situation clear?

---

THIS is the Solution to my problem. I'd like to insert here this solution to help all the visitors that have my own problem.

@Rahul, I've tried to do what you've written and it does not work. The problem is in "name is null". I've tried also "name = null", but nothing got better! So I changed the column matched: I've chosen Student (that had 0 as default value) and I wrote as you told me. So:

```
WHERE Student = '0' LIMIT 1
```

Limit 1 force the program to write ONLY the first and not all the other. Now it works! 
So I thank you!

Comment: show your code please

Comment: "Blank" row? It sounds like you should be using a SQL `insert`.

Comment: I would delete "blank" rows and INSERT new rows.  You don't need to find record to update, this is what the database does for you.

Comment: Peter, in which way database does it for me? I have to update some rows, but i don't want to update ever the same row!! So i'd like to browse the rows..

Comment: What do you even mean by the "first" blank row. SQL gives no guarentee of any order, unless you explicitly use "order by". In this case you really need to define what you're ordering by, in order to find the "first" of something.

Comment: I try to explain again my situation: I have to write on DB some data. So I have implemented a method that write arguments that are passed to it. Considering that I have to call this method more than once, I need the method to write automatically on the first raw that is not written yet, in this way I can compile DB. Have I been enough understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think of database tables like Excel tables which you can scroll down endlessly to find an infinite number of empty rows. But this is not how SQL databases work. A database table only consists of rows with data. The table just ends after the last filled row.

Usually, a database table has no "blank" rows (Not that it is technically impossible to have at least one empty row, but it is rather uncommon). When you want to add new entries to a table, you use the INSERT command:

```
INSERT INTO subject VALUES ("English", "Bob");
```

This will add a new row to the table. Assuming that your table has two columns, these two fields of the new row will now have the values "English" and "Bob".

The UPDATE command is used to change one or more rows which are already in the table

```
UPDATE subject SET subject="Math" WHERE name="Bob";
```

This command will search for all rows where the name is "Bob" and change the subject to "Math".

Comment: I thank you. But I have a yet implemented Database (with rows that have only some columns to be written by user). Your hint is to create a new row every time are inserted new data?

Comment: @Bernheart yes, that's what you do when you add new entries to an SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the blank row in a column you can write this:-

```
select * from table where column IS NULL;
```

Try this:-

```
public void updateDB (String name, int student){ 
try 
{
    final String q = "UPDATE subject SET name=?, student=? WHERE name = (select name from subject where name is null");
    final PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
    ps.setString(1,name);
    ps.setInt(2,student);
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: first depends on an order, so you need to do an `order by`

Comment: Mmm i think that it's not a good way.. it's quite strange that there is not a method in the API for doing this

Comment: Rahul, I have to put the name in the DB. How can I match with the name that I have to put in??

Comment: By the way, I've tried to do what you have written matching in other ways: the result is that ALL the rows that matched have been written.. Are you really sure that ONLY the first match has to be written?

Comment: @Bernheart:- If you want to update only the first row then you have to use LIMIT 1 ie, select name from subject where name is null LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the correct way to use a PreparedStatement:

They way you are doing it is open for all kinds of SQL Injection attacks as well as being just plain incorrect.

```
final String q = "UPDATE subject SET name=?, student=? WHERE name = (select name from subject where name is null");
final PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(q);
ps.setString(1,name);
ps.setInt(2,student);
final int recsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Read the JavaDocs [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

#### This makes no logical sense:

```
WHERE name = (select name from subject where name is null)
```

is basically saying `WHERE name is null`, if this is your intention the sub-Select here is the incorrect way of doing this.

#### You need to do what you want to do in Java most likely:

From a comment:

> "I have to update some rows, but i don't want to update ever the same
>   row!! So i'd like to browse the rows."

I assume you have a list of things you want to update the *blank* rows each with different data. Without seeing the exact schema of your table, and the data that it is populated with this is going to be impossible for anyone on the internet to answer your question.

Update your question with the schema DDL and some example of the entire rows of data that you want to update and maybe someone can help you further. Otherwise this question will get put on hold.